# Laravel: prevent changing other users' items

Tags: laravel

I have three models. I want to avoid that users can change the todo's from todolists belonging to other users.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function todolists()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Todolist');
    }

    public function todos()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Todo', 'App\Todolist');
    }
}

class Todolist extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function todos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Todo');
    }
}

class Todo extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'completed' => 'boolean',
    ];

    public function todolist()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Todolist');
    }
}
```

To avoid users can view other users' todolists and todo items, I have implemented the following:

```
 public function getTodosForTodolist(Todolist $todolist)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->id == $todolist->user_id) {
            $todos = Todo::where('todolist_id', $todolist->id )->get();
            return view('todo/index', ['todos' => $todos); 
        }
        else {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }
    }
```

Next step is to prevent that users can edit other users' todo items. Currently in the TodoController I have simply the following:

```
public function edit(Todo $todo)
        {
         if (Auth::user()->todos->id == $todo->todolist->id) {
            return view('todo/edit', ['todo' => $todo]);
         }
    }
```

This gives the following error:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

The error is because the current user has multiple todos. So I changed my code as follows.

```
public function edit(Todo $todo)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->todos->first()->id == $todo->todolist->id) {
            return view('todo/edit', ['todo' => $todo]);
        }
        abort('403', 'Unauthorized action.'); 
}
```

This works but it just feels very wrong to do this as such.

What would be a better way to accomplish that users' can view/edit/delete items belonging to other users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#writing-policies) for your Todo and TodoList models and a scope to restrict todos to one user to prevent duplicated code within your app:

```
class ToDoListPolicy
{
    public function view(User $user, TodoList $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $todolist->user_id;
    }
}

class ToDoPolicy
{
    public function edit(User $user, Todo $toDo)
    {
        $toDo->loadMissing('todolist');
        
        return $user->id === $toDo->todolist->user_id;
    }
}
```

Register them in your **AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        TodoList::class => ToDoListPolicy::class,
        Todo::class => ToDoPolicy::class
    ];
}
```

and then use them in your actions:

```
public function getTodosForTodolist(Todolist $toDoList)
{
    $this->authorize('view', $toDoList);
    
    $toDoList->loadMissing('todos');
    
    return view('todo.index', ['todos' => $toDoList->todos); 
}

class ToDoController extends Controller
{
    public function edit(Todo $toDo)
    {
        $this->authorize('edit', $toDo);
        
        return view('todo.edit', compact('toDo'));
    } 
}
```

And a scope to restrict the query to a specific user:

```
class Todo extends Model {
    // ...
    
    public function scopeByUser(Builder $query, ?User $user = null)
    {
        if (! $user) {
            $user = Auth::user();
        }
        
        $query->whereHas('todolist', function (Builder $toDoListQuery) use ($user) {
            $toDoListQuery->where('user_id', $user->id);
        });
    }
}
```

---

Answer to [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929198/laravel-prevent-changing-other-users-items#comment107823681_60930153) in the comments.

> Q1: I had to put `Auth::user()->can('view', $todolist);` in an if-else clause for it to work. Guess this is the way it works?
>
> Q2: what is the difference between `$this->authorize('edit', $todo)` and `Auth::user()->can('edit', $todo)`?

Sorry, that was a mistake on my side. [`Auth::user()->can()`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/Access/Authorizable.html#method_can) returns a boolean whereas [`$this->authorize()`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/AuthorizesRequests.html#method_authorize) (which is a method of the AuthorizesRequests trait usually included in the BaseController) [throws an exception](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L328) if the authorization failed.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out. Can you advise what this loadMissing does exactly? And also why a scope is required here?

Comment: `loadMissing()` basically eager loads the relation if not done already. The scope is there to prevent double code in the case you want to fetch todos by a specific user.

Comment: Thanks man, this works. Just couple of questions. Question 1: I had to put `Auth::user()->can('view', $todolist);` in an if-else clause for it to work. Guess this is the way it worksl? Question 2: what is the difference between `$this->authorize('edit', $todo);` and `Auth::user()->can('edit', $todo)`. Can they replace one another?

Comment: I've answered your questions in my answer. It was a bit too much for the comments. Could you tell me if `getTodosForTodolist()` is a method of a controller, so I can fix the issue with `Auth::user()->can()`?

Comment: Yes, getTodosForTodolist() is method inside Todo controller.

Comment: Then there shouldn't be a problem replacing `Auth::user()->can()` with `$this->authorize()`. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to let each user work only with his/her own Todos then adding a Global Scope is what you are looking for. This implementation will let your application feel that Todos ( of users other than the logged one ) does not exist.

Global Scopes can be used for many models which means it will reduce boiler plate code.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#global-scopes

Comment: Correct, Global scopes is what you are looking for. Read it, use it ;)

Comment: I implemented Laravel Policies in the meantime. Why would Global Scopes be preferred?

Comment: @wiwa1978 Global scopes allow you to add constraints to all queries for a given model.
This means that you don't have to care about adding `where` throughout your application. And I think that you want to put this `where` most of the time you retrieve `Todo` model. `Policies` are not for this job. You will get it as you develop this application, further.